# How to read from a txt file and and seperate the text based on numbers and strings in Java

Tags: java, list, java.util.scanner

The program is reading from a text file. Each line of the text file starts with a number from -2 to 2. The number is the then followed by a sentence. Please see below for the first three lines of the txt file:

```
1 Campanella gets the tone just right -- funny in the middle of sad in the middle of hopeful .
-2 Nothing more than an amiable but unfocused bagatelle that plays like a loosely-connected string of acting-workshop exercises .
1 It 's a sharp movie about otherwise dull subjects .
1 ... it 's as comprehensible as any Dummies guide , something even non-techies can enjoy .
-1 -LRB- Green is -RRB- the comedy equivalent of Saddam Hussein , and I 'm just about ready to go to the U.N. and ask permission for a preemptive strike .
```

The only lines that should be read are the ones that have a number, one space and then text in that order. The last two lines should not be considered because they have `...` and `-` respectively before the text. The first three sentences are fine however.

I have a class called `placeholder` with the following fields:

```
public class placeholder implements Comparable<placeholder> {
    protected int score;
    protected String text;

    public placeholder(int score, String text) {
        this.score = score;
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

I would like a method called `readFile` to go by line by line and store every single line into a list called `reviewsDB`.  Each object in the list will be of type `placeholder` and the number at the start of the line will by the `score` value and the following words will be the `text` value.  What code can I put in the following area to break each line up between the number and text?

```
    public static List<placeholder> readFile(String filename) {

        File movieReviews = new File("reviews.txt");

        try {

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(movieReviews);
            scanner.nextLine();

            List<placeholder> reviewsDB = new ArrayList<placeholder>();

            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                int sentenceScore = 0;
                String sentenceText = null;

                //code to separate the number and text in each line here
                placeholder newSentence = new placeholder(sentenceScore, sentenceText);

                reviewsDB.add(newSentence);
            }

            return reviewsDB;
        }

        catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("Something went wrong");

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hello, there is always one space between the number and the sentence  for every line?

Comment: @dariosicily thank you for taking an interest in this. For the most part, it is the case that the series goes number, then space, then text. There are a few edge cases that I edited into my question that need to be ignored if it does not follow that series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex. It's best to match patterns. You may have n number of characters, positive-negative also. You can add `(-|+)` if you have `+` also at the beginning.

Hope you don't have scientific notations.

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    int sentenceScore = 0;
    String sentenceText = null;
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
    // code to separate the number and text in each line here
    placeholder newSentence = new placeholder(sentenceScore, sentenceText);

    reviewsDB.add(newSentence);
}
```

I used the below regex

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(-?\\d+)(.*)");
```

`-` is optional - `-?` meant this
Then one or more digits - `\d+`

Then the second group is any character after the first group - `(.*)`

You can play with your inputs [here](https://regex101.com/r/NPVXUR/1) I tested your input here.

Comment: Awesome, thank so much! I'm implementing now. We do you put the ```Pattern p ``` line of code? Before the while loop or inside of the while loop?

Comment: Yes, Before starting the loop - to avoid repeated initialization.

Comment: this is great. So as of now, it looks like the code is just printing out the numbers and then the following text for only the sentences that match the criteria correct?

Comment: @FinDev Yes Exactly

Comment: So if I add these two lines of code in your if loop I should have the correct list?  ```Sentence newSentence = new Sentence(Integer.parseInt(m.group(1)), m.group(2));``` and ```reviewsDB.add(newSentence);```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work as the line ```-1 -LRB- Green is -RRB- the comedy equivalent of Saddam Hussein , and I 'm just about ready to go to the U.N. and ask permission for a preemptive strike .``` is still being added even tho it should be excluded due to the text starting with ```-```

Comment: Then you should remove - hyphen from the REGEX.

Answer (score 2):

- Read the file into a stream using `Files#lines`
- Filter the lines which meet your criteria using regex `"-?\\d\\s\\w+.*"`
- Split each line into two parts using String#split using space as delimeter and limit the resulting array to a length of two `line.split("\\s",2)`
- Collect the stream to a list of `Placeholder` objects

Example code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<placeholder> list= readFile("path to your file");
        list.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    public static List<placeholder> readFile(String filename) {
        List<Placeholder> reviewsDB = new ArrayList<>();
        try (Stream<String> content = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename))) {
            reviewsDB = content
                    .filter(line -> line.matches("-?\\d\\s\\w+.*"))
                    .map(line -> line.split("\\s",2))
                    .map(arr -> new placeholder(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]), arr[1]))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reviewsDB;
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding the regex used for filtering, a _word_ character, i.e. `\w`, is also an underscore or a digit, as well as an alphabetic character. Perhaps `[a-zA-Z]` would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Eritrean awesome, thank you so much. I will work on implementation right now!

Comment: @Abra Thank you for your comment. I just wanted to filter out the dots and the minus symbol provided in the example of OP. If necessary, the OP can adapt it according to his wishes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)` to get a List of Strings representing the content of your file. Then you can iterate through the list and use `String.split(Regex, Limit)` to split the string in parts. Then you can create a new Placeholder-Object from the parts.

See:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.charset.Charset-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm looking into how to implement this now